# R, tmap: Legend with text both sides

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to create a legend in Tmap that has text on both sides of the color classifications, as shown here:

[image: Desired legend]

Minimal working example:

```
library(tmap)
data("World")
    
tm_shape(World) + tm_polygons("HPI")
```

Produces the standard legend with text only on the RHS:

[image]

Looking through TMAP documentation, there is no direct solution to solve this problem.

Any help/suggestion from the community would be welcomed.